# VBA error on selecting "No" or "Cancel" when asked to replace file during SaveAs

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that I use to save the workbook in a specific folder with a specific name.  The problem comes along when a file already exists.  I have the "ConflictResolution" set to ask the user but I get "Run-time error 1004: Method SaveAs of object _Workbook failed" when the user selects `No` or `Cancel` on the dialog.

I'm not sure how or if it's possible to just exit on `No` or `Cancel` or if I should just add in custom error handling to this section?

```
  NewFileType = "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm," & _
               "All files (*.*), *.*"

    NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:=SaveArea & newfilename, _
        fileFilter:=NewFileType)

    If NewFile <> "" And NewFile <> "False" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=NewFile, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
            CreateBackup:=False, _
            ConflictResolution:=xlUserResolution
    End If
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should handle the error that is raised by the SaveAs method.  E.g.

```
 If NewFile <> "" And NewFile <> "False" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFile, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
        CreateBackup:=False, _
        ConflictResolution:=xlUserResolution
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
 End If
```

Or alternatively, check if the file exists before calling SaveAs

Comment: Works great, thanks!  I've kept the user resolution in case they do want to replace it, was just stuck on this issue that doesn't come up very often.

Comment: :+1: except `On Error Resume Next` doesn't *handle* an error, it *shoves it under the carpet* and keeps the code running in a potentially unstable state. *Handling* the error would mean having an *error-handling subroutine* and an `On Error GoTo [ErrorHandler]` jump instead.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I agree that `On Error Resume Next` is not a best practice for handling errors as it requires the developer to explicitly test the Err object after every statement that may raise an error.  But it's not unreasonable to use it for the duration of one statement as in the above example.